# Titanium dynamic styles of view

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I want to remove the inline styling of programatic elements and keep the styles all inside tss classes. Right now I have to do something like this:

```
var featureRow = Ti.UI.createView({layout: 'vertical'});

//For context: I add various images/labels inside before appending the view 
var featureImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({ image: param+".png" });
featureRow.add(featureImage);
...
$.featureTable.add(row);
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
var featureRow = Ti.UI.createView({ class: 'featureRow');
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to add class like below,

```
$.addClass(yourView, "yourClassName");
```

add your class in .tss file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Titanium Alloy as of version 1.20, here is the link to instructions on how:

> [Guide: Dynamic Styling in Alloy](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Dynamic_Styles)

In a nutshell, you can create styles in code, or in *.tss files, and then apply them using 
[`Alloy.Controller.addClass`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Alloy.Controller)